# scheduling meteor.js on crontab

Tags: meteor, cron

I have a meteor.js application I've created to run locally on OSX on my laptop. Every so often, meteor stops running for unexplained reasons (like after the computer returns from sleep).

I'd like to schedule a process on cron to check every minute if meteor is working, and if it's not, launch it.  I placed the following in my crontab:

```
* * * * * ps aux | grep meteor | grep -v grep || cd ~/path_to_my_meteor_project/;  nohup meteor &
```

This command works at launching meteor when I enter it manually in terminal. But when scheduled in cron, it does not seem to do anything.

Comment: Be aware that Meteor does not launch a `meteor` process, instead it launches 2 regular node processes.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely to be caused by the fact cron expects a binary file (or a script to launch) whereas, when typed in a terminal, your command is interpreted by bash, which understands logic such as `||`.

In order to fix this, you will have to create a bash script containing the line of code working in your terminal, then ask cron to run it every minute.